# 2 questions about Windows Server Admin accounts

Tags: windows

I'm trying to setup a security policy and am a bit stuck - and wonder whether anyone can help me. I've got 2 questions that I can't seem to find the answers to.

1. Is it possible to set up a master system administrator account under a Windows Server OS that is protected from interference by other system administrators?
2. Is there a way to set up an user with all privileges necessary to maintain a system under Windows server except the ability to set up and modify usercodes and passwords?

I've tried searching on the internet for hours, but keep getting responses for Server Administrator jobs - and can't seem to pinpoint any specific answer. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to both, but it would be an extraordinary amount of work. In general don't give people admin privileges unless they absolutely need them and you can absolutely trust them.

You can do things like make people administrators over certain groups of computers fairly easily by putting them in a new group (Call it SubAdmins of XYZ), then using a GPO to add SubAdmins of XYZ to the Local Admin group of those computers.